# Problem of ending return statement on canActivate

Tags: angular, typescript, canactivate

I have a problem when I use CanActivate method: error ts2366 "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include undefined" appears.

Following my code:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isAuth) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to add '| undefined' after boolean but an other error told me it was incompatible with CanActivate.

Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: You are supposed to return either a `boolean` or a `UrlTree` from `canActivate`. If you return the UrlTree it will deal with the navigation for you, so you don't need to call `this.router.navigate` yourself (see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: @cdimitroulas So, if I understand, I need to return a ```this.router.parseUrl('/auth')``` in the second case and the navigate will be automaticaly done with this UrlTree ?

Comment: I believe so - I haven't actually worked with Angular so I'm basing this off what is written in the docs link I sent in my previous comment.

Comment: @cdimitroulas thanks for your answer, it is solved.

Comment: I'm going to add a proper answer to your question - if you could mark it as the correct answer I would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to return either a `boolean` or a `UrlTree` from `canActivate`. If you return the `UrlTree` it will deal with the navigation for you, so you don't need to call this.router.navigate yourself (see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Your code might look like this:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isAuth) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/auth');
    }
  }
}
```